# Powershell Help to compare

Tags: azure-powershell

Hope you all are safe and well !!

I am running a script that gives me Azure AD apps with its secret end date property. The property name which gives me all details in Azure AD is “PasswordCredentials” and I am using get-azureadapplication cmdlet.

What is the best way to check If the app has end date value within a month and filter on it, I tried where-object with get-date.adddays(30) and tried to compare with -lt operators.

Appreciate your support here.

Comment: Can you share what you already have coded?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here is the code I am using but giving me an expired one as well. I will check the code given by Joy with UTC time.




Get-AzureADApplication -all $true | where {$_.passwordcredentials.enddate -notlike “” -and $_.passwordcredentials.enddate -LE ((get-date).AddDays(30))} | select @{Name=”DisplayName”; Expression={$_.displayname}}, @{Name=”EndDate”; Expression={$_.passwordcredentials.enddate}} | sort enddate | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\SecretExpiredandExpring.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your case, you should note there may be several `PasswordCredentials` for one app, so you need to use a loop to check every `PasswordCredential`.

And the `EndDate` you got from the `Get-AzureADApplication` command is a `UTC` time, but `Get-Date` returns the local time, so you need to use `(Get-Date).AddDays(30).ToUniversalTime()` instead of `(Get-Date).AddDays(30)`. Also, if you just want to check the expiring ones, you must exclude the ones that have expired, so use `$PasswordCredential.EndDate -gt $nowdate` like below.

As you did not give your script, I can just give a sample for you, my sample is for a single app, if you want to check all the apps in your tenant, use a loop to do that.

```
$PasswordCredentials = (Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <object-id>).PasswordCredentials 
$nowdate = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$wantdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(30).ToUniversalTime()
foreach($PasswordCredential in $PasswordCredentials){
    if($PasswordCredential.EndDate -lt $wantdate -and $PasswordCredential.EndDate -gt $nowdate){
        $keyid = $PasswordCredential.KeyId
        Write-Output "The key with KeyId $keyid will expire"
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to get the `AppId` and `AppName`, you could use the script below.

```
$apps = Get-AzureADApplication -All $true
$nowdate = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$wantdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(30).ToUniversalTime()
foreach($app in $apps){
    $PasswordCredentials = $app.PasswordCredentials
    $appid = $app.AppId
    $displayname = $app.DisplayName
    foreach($PasswordCredential in $PasswordCredentials){
        if($PasswordCredential.EndDate -lt $wantdate -and $PasswordCredential.EndDate -gt $nowdate){
            $a = $app | select  @{Name="AppId"; Expression={$appid}}, @{Name="DisplayName"; Expression={$displayname}}, @{Name="EndDate"; Expression={$PasswordCredential.EndDate}} 
            Write-Output $a
        }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Joy for your help, I am using below cmdlet and giving me expired one as well and not converting time also.




Get-AzureADApplication -all $true | where {$_.passwordcredentials.enddate -notlike “” -and $_.passwordcredentials.enddate -LE ((get-date).AddDays(30))} | select @{Name=”DisplayName”; Expression={$_.displayname}}, @{Name=”EndDate”; Expression={$_.passwordcredentials.enddate}} | sort enddate | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\SecretExpiredandExpring.csv




I will try to check your code above and get back with the result. Thank you again.

Comment: I am getting details using below but it is also giving me expired one.

If I use your script then it does not tell me app ID or name? ANy way to get or correct below?

$nowdate = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$wantdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(30).ToUniversalTime()


Get-AzureADApplication -all $true  | where {$_.passwordcredentials.enddate -gt $nowdate -and $_.passwordcredentials.enddate -lt $wantdate} | 

select @{Name=”DisplayName”; Expression={$_.displayname}}, @{Name=”EndDate”; Expression={$_.passwordcredentials.enddate}}

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick ...

Appreciate your efforts and help #StaySafe